# PhotosPicker doesn't work if maxSelectionCount is more than "1"

Tags: swiftui, photospicker

```
PhotosPicker(selection: $vm.selectedItemsTest, 
             maxSelectionCount: 10, 
             selectionBehavior: .continuous, 
             matching: .images) {
                 Image(systemName: "trophy")
                     //.font(.system(size: scaled16*1.5))
                     .font(Font.system(size: scaled16*1.5, weight: .regular))
                     .foregroundColor(Color.black)
             }.onChange(of: vm.selectedItemsTest) { newValue in
                 print("print selected")
             }
```

This is the sample code. It used to work until I updated Xcode from 14.3 to 15.

If maxSelectionCount is 1, everything works well. But if it is more than one, PhotosPicker opens up the photo library. However, when I select a photo, it automatically and quickly deselects it again.

Trying to select multiple photos, but I can't.

Comment: Is `$vm.selectedItemsTest` a single `PhotosPickerItem` or an array `[PhotosPickerItem]`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for asking, and sorry for not sharing everything and being transparent. I defined the variable like this; @Published var selectedItemsTest: [PhotosPickerItem] = []

Comment: Your code works well in my tests. There is nothing wrong with the code you show, unless there is
 more code that you don't show and affects the execution.
You should show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
I'm on MacOS 14, Xcode 15, tested on real ios17 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst and macOS.
 It could be different on older systems.